# Meaning of "gets no better"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Today I saw a girl with a T-shirt where were written "Gets no better". I can't understand what it means. I litteraly can translate it, but it makes no sense for me...

My best bet would be "I have nothing better to offer than what you see", but what makes me doubt is the "s" at the end of "get"... For this meaning, I would have said "got no better" instead...
Or maybe it means this is the T-shirt speaking, saying "[she] gets no better" maybe ?

Can anyone tell me more about this ? How would you understand it ?

Please feel free to correct my english since I'm learning :)

Comment: If it is a woman, I would guess "(It) gets no better" meaning "It gets no better than what you see." Saying she is the best looking compared to others. But the "better" could relate to anything. Better at math, cooking, etc.

Comment: @user3169 But why using "it" for "it gets no better" ?

Comment: It's idiomatic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is a shortening (to fit on the T-shirt) of the words **"it gets no better than this"**. There are at least two interpretations: (1) The lady wearing the shirt is perfect. (2) The part of the lady's anatomy upon which the words are positioned may be significant, so the words are a sexual innuendo.

Comment: I'm really confused with the usage of "it gets"... would you have some other examples whith the same structure ?

Comment: +1.   Sitting back in a beach chair, sipping a cool drink while looking at the sunset in Tahiti. "It doesn't get any better than this."

Comment: @TRomano Thanks for the example. I guess it may be an idiomatic structure, which has nothing to do with the normal meaning of "get" ?

Comment: @Random: "To get" can also mean "to become, to come to pass".  It does not become any better than this.  Something better than this does not exist.

Comment: @Random: are you familiar with so-called "dummy" or "expletive" **It**?

Comment: @TRomano if you mean like in "It's ok", "It's raining", yes, but sounds like not that much... (by the way, what do you mean by "dummy" ? I'm surprised to see it in that context...) I think the problem is I understand "to get better" as a mood, something like "it gets no better if you drink"...

Comment: "dummy" is just another term for "expletive".   You could also say "Things" get no better than this.  **It** is a vague existential reference.  The world has nothing better to offer than this.

Comment: @TRomano would "it can't be better" be a good way to say the same thing ?

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head. In fact, there's a chance the T-shirt is a spin-off of the old beer commercial tagline: [*It doesn't get any better than this*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fg6YC2AXqQo), and relies on the reader being familiar with that famous phrase.

Answer (score 1):

It's short for "It doesn't get any better" which, in my opinion, may mean that since everything's fine, there's no need for improving it.

On the other hand, were it written,say, on the wall, it might mean that everything has been bad and still is.